# Color scale formatting in Excel 2007 based on "good" center value/absolute value

Tags: excel

Imagine I have a cell that I want to be red if the value is 2000, yellow if it is +-200 and red if it is +-500. Excel doesn't seem to want to let me have a good center value, with any value that is too high or too low being bad values.

The closest I can get is a 3 color gradient where it is red/green/red, with no yellow intermediate coloring. I attempted to use a formula based on absolute value, where I set the minimum color to green with a formula of abs(a1-2000)=0, yellow midpoint of abs(a1-2000)=200 and red maximum of abs(a1-2000)=500 but Excel won't allow me to use relative references in formulas for color scale formatting.

Anyone have any ideas?

Edit: I should clarify that I'm using Excel 2007

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create 3 new rules of the **Format only cells that contain** type, all **stop if true**:

1. for exactly 2000 red
2. for between 1800 and 2200 yellow
3. for between 1500 and 2500 red.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you that is definitely an option! I was hoping to take advantage of the gradient formatting so that the color would reflect how far away the value is from the center value though. If there's no way to do it, then I'll settle for the absolute colors. Thanks!

Comment: i see the point now ;) that would require 5-Color scale or use of dynamic ranges in "Applies to", none of which looks possible :(

Comment: Yeah a 5 color scale option was what I first looked for :( The absolute colors will work though! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Use as many hidden cells at 2000 as required to skew the average towards 2000. You can select all those extra cells when creating the rule, then hide them.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is clever, but bound to cause problems!